# Why does my cosine similarity function return an inconsistent result?

Tags: python, string-matching, cosine-similarity, n-gram

I want to do a name matching using Python and found some article that uses ngrams and cosine similarity function to do that.

Here is my `ngrams` function:

```
def ngrams(string, n=3):
    string = str(string)
    string = fix_text(string) # fix text
    string = string.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode() #remove non ascii chars
    string = string.lower()
    chars_to_remove = [")","(",".","|","[","]","{","}","'"]
    rx = "[" + re.escape("".join(chars_to_remove)) + "]"
    string = re.sub(rx, "", string)
    string = string.replace("&", "and")
    string = string.replace(",", " ")
    string = string.replace("-", " ")
    string = string.title() # normalise case - capital at start of each word
    string = re.sub(" +"," ",string).strip() # get rid of multiple spaces and replace with a single
    string = " "+ string +" " # pad names for ngrams...
    string = re.sub(r"[,-./]|\sBD",r"", string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return ["".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

Using this function, I can get the matrix for my data using TF IDF Vectorizer like this.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(name)
```

I make 2 matrix A and B to compare later using cosine similarity function.

```
def awesome_cossim_top(A, B, ntop, lower_bound=0):
    if not isspmatrix_csr(A):
        A = A.tocsr()

    if not isspmatrix_csr(B):
        B = B.tocsr()

    M, K1 = A.shape
    K2, N = B.shape

    idx_dtype = np.int32

    nnz_max = M*ntop

    indptr = np.empty(M+1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    indices = np.empty(nnz_max, dtype=idx_dtype)
    data = np.empty(nnz_max, dtype=A.dtype)

    ct.sparse_dot_topn(
        M, N, np.asarray(A.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(A.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        A.data,
        np.asarray(B.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(B.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        B.data,
        ntop,
        lower_bound,
        indptr, indices, data)

    return csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(M, N))
```

and call it with this code:

```
matches = awesome_cossim_top(tf_idf_matrix_A, tf_idf_matrix_B.transpose(), 10, 0)
```

But I don't get a consistent result. For example, I run it against this data:

| index | name A | name B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Abram | Abram |
| 1 | Ace | Ace |

the result are:

| A | B | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

When I reverse the data, it doesn't return a similar result.

| index | name A | name B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Abram | Ace |
| 1 | Ace | Abram |

The results are:

| A | B | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0,571239953724207 |
| 0 | 1 | 0,27197690175892 |
| 1 | 0 | 0,571239953724207 |
| 1 | 1 | 0,543953803517839 |

Why the results are far off, and what can I do to make it consistent? Something like:

| A | B | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0,571239953724207 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0,543953803517839 |

Comment: Those results seem pretty reasonable to me for your inputs. Why do you expect them to be independent of row order?

Comment: @matthias, I expect for the same data (A[0] and B[1]; A[1] and B[0]) to be 1 in similarity value. Or is my understanding of the similarity value is wrong?

Comment: It should be the same, since the cosine-similarity is symmetric (its just the angle between the two vectors).

Comment: @CutePoison yes I think it should be the same too. So, am I using the function incorrectly?